# How i get data and returned in json format in zf2?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, zend-framework2

I used mongo odm query for getting data according to id i want to get query data and return this data in json format,how i do this?
here is my code:

```
public function loadAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');

        $data = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('Calendar\Document\Event')
                ->field('calendar_id')->equals($id)->getQuery()->execute();
        //$count_tags = $eventdata->count();
            $array = array();
            if($data && !is_null($data) && is_object($data)){   

            foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
                $array[] = $value;
            }
        }


            return $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($array));
    }
```

Comment: Can you not open a question for every single little task you're facing and eventually try to use google first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplished this by following

```
return new JsonModel($arrayVaraible);
```

you might need to import

```
Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
```

Hope That helps